# Required fields won't validate

Tags: html, forms, validation

I have this form:

```
            <form id="br" method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]) ?>">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Report Title:*</td> <td><input name="title" type="text" required placeholder="The bug that you want to report" size="50" maxlength="35" /></td><td></td>
                    </tr><br />
                    <tr>
                        <td>Reporter:*</td> <td><input name="user" type="text" required class="username" placeholder="Your name" size="50" maxlength="35"></td><td><input type="checkbox" name="anonymous" id="cb" /><label for="cb">Report anonymously</label></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="vertical-align: top;">Report summary:*&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td> <td><textarea name="sum" cols="39" rows="15" required id="sum"></textarea></td></td><td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr><td style="font-size:12px;"><em>* - required field</em></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
                </table>
                <br />
                <a href="#" class="submit"><div class="submitform"></div></a>
                <br />
            </form>
```

But the required fields won't validate, even if I put the `required` attribute to them. It would immediately submit the form without validating anymore...

Answer (score 0):

ok , i got it

```
<a href="#" class="submit"><div class="submitform"></div></a>
```

It should be

```
 <input type="submit" name="submit" />
```

Comment: Tried putting the `="required"` values to the `required` attributes but still don't work. And one more thing, I am using `HTML5` here as my doctype and not `XHTML`

Comment: I have changed the answer, you were not using `<input type="submit" />` . You were using `<a href="..."` .

Comment: I have equipped a jQuery code to the `<a href="#"...` that is triggered on click. Won't `$("form#br").submit();` do it?

I have tried putting the submit button that you suggested and it works. But I want the submit button to be an image, so I used the anchor and a div with a background image instead...